# How to generate Fibonacci sequence using RxJava 1?

Tags: android, rx-java, fibonacci

Fibonacci is just a handy example of a more general problem where the next element depends on the previous ones. https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Problem-Solving-Examples-in-RxJava offer some nice ways to do it but they are still bit hacky. [generate()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Phantom-Operators#generate-and-generateabsolutetime) is also recommended but not available in RxJava 1.

What could be an alternative way to do this? Is there an equivalent to [generate()](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Phantom-Operators#generate-and-generateabsolutetime) ?

Comment: why to do this with RxJava at all? Why do you want to create this problem for you? This doesn't look like a real life problem.

Comment: Why RxJava? Because it does not have states to manage and we can easily send this operation to a background thread. This is a real problem. If a server is implemented to send new data from a timestamp to a client, I have to include the timestamp of the previous response in the network request. This will make the next request depends on the previous request timestamp.

Comment: There is the `SyncOnSubscribe` in 1.x for that purpose.

Comment: For the general case when you want to know the previous element, use the `scan` operator.

Comment: @akarnokd Thank you. this is probably what I want.

Comment: @TassosBassoukos `scan` can be a bit hacky. Have you read this  https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Problem-Solving-Examples-in-RxJava?

Answer (score -1):

```java
        final int number = 9;
        // [0,] 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34
        final Observable<Integer> fibonacci = Observable.just(0).repeat().scan(new Pair<Integer, Integer>(0, 1), new Func2<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Integer, Pair<Integer, Integer>>() {
            @Override
            public Pair<Integer, Integer> call(Pair<Integer, Integer> pair, Integer integer) {
//                Log.d(String.format("pair: %s, int: %s", pair, integer));
                int lhs = pair.getValue();
                int rhs = pair.getKey() + lhs;
                return new Pair<Integer, Integer>(lhs, rhs);
            }
        }).map(new Func1<Pair<Integer, Integer>, Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer call(Pair<Integer, Integer> pair) {
//                Log.d(String.format("map: %s", pair));
                return pair.getValue();
            }
        });
        final List<Integer> result = fibonacci.take(number).toList().toBlocking().single();
        Log.d(String.format("%s", result));
```

Comment: Downvoted? I believe it does answer the question "How to generate Fibonacci sequence using RxJava 1?".

Comment: I did not downvote it, but the is an example in  https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Problem-Solving-Examples-in-RxJava which I did not ask for.